# Mongodb database schema design issue

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have two collections in my mongodb database :- Users , Clubs

```
User Schema :- 
var UserSchema = new Schema({
Name: {
    type: String ,
    required: true
},
Clubs: [
    {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Club'}
]});
```

Now when a user joins a club , i update the club array . But I also frequently need to fetch all the users for a particular club . Therefore I am creating the club schema as :-

```
var ClubSchema = new Schema({
clubName : {
    type: String , 
    unique: true ,
    required: true
},
members : [
{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
    ref: 'User' , 
    default: []
} ]});
```

My question is : Is this the right way to do so , or should I maintain this club information at the User Collection only ? Maybe I need to optimize the query related to fetching all the Users belonging to a Club.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite hard to say what's "the right way" to be honest, as this is most likely case by case depending on your application queries and architecture.

I have seen some people do as you designed above; Solving many-to-many relationships by using reference in both collection.
This would work for your case queries above:

> db.user.find({"clubs": ObjectId("000000")});  #Find all users belonging to certain club.
> db.club.find({"users": ObjectId("111111")}); # Find all clubs where a user belong to.

With two indexes on:

> db.user.ensureIndex({"clubs": 1});
>
> db.club.ensureIndex({"users": 1});

Though this may reduce the overall consistency. i.e. when you delete a club, you need to update the other affected documents as well. While in the process of the mentioned update, your documents may not be up-to-date.
If you don't have mongodb on replicas, not accessing the db from distributed systems and you think this problem is not a big issue, then go for this design for the ease of query.

If you think the consistency mentioned above is a deal-breaker,
then go with inserting only clubs reference in users collection.
This is probably the most common design, and the one listed in
mongodb official site.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/

I would suggest optimising your query first, before choosing to add complexities in your update/insert (Because you have to update all related docs by having ref in Users and Clubs).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion . I'll go with the  second option and change it if the fetching query becomes the bottleneck.